# PHP cURL return empty header and body despite HTTP Code 200

Tags: php, string, http, curl

So I try to scrap this URL: xxxx.fr with cURL, but impossible to get access to the page HTML code, both header and body are empty.
HTTP code return is 200
I tried with other URL (different domain) and it works like a charm.
I also try with different User Agent and Referer

Do you know what is wrong ? At lest can someone try this code on your own server and let me know if you have the same issue ?

Thank you

Below is my code:

```
  $url = 'http://www.xxxx.fr';

  $header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = ""; // BROWSERS USUALLY LEAVE BLANK

  $curl = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.fr");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $curlData = curl_exec($curl);

  $infos = curl_getinfo($curl);
  print_r($infos);

  curl_close ( $curl );

  echo "<hr>Page:<br />";
  echo htmlentities($curlData);
```

and here is the result from the print_r($infos):

```
Array ( 
[url] => http://www.xxxx.fr 
[content_type] => text/html 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 625 
[request_size] => 465 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0.032535 
[namelookup_time] => 0.001488 
[connect_time] => 0.002581 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.002639 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 10234 
[speed_download] => 314553 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => -1 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.032088 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
[primary_ip] => xxx 
[primary_port] => 80 
[local_ip] => xxx 
[local_port] => 37319 
[redirect_url] => 
[request_header] => GET / HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0 Host: www.xxxx.fr Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Referer: http://www.google.fr Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 
)
```

Comment: So `$curlData` is empty for you? That is coming back with HTML for me when I execute your code.

Comment: also when i try curl -v command on my server I can get HTML code, so I think there is something blocking in my PHP / cURL config, but not sure what....

Comment: actually, if I do a var_dump($curlData), it print the HTML code, but otherwise it's empty. It's strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//EDIT

htmlentities($curlData) returns empty string because encoding of source is non UTF-8 string [see this link](http://www.justria.com/2014/05/29/htmlspecialchars-htmlentities-returns-empty-string/)

that should works:

```
 htmlentities($curlData, ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1' );
```

> in PHP 5.4 release, htmlspecialchars() doesn’t use ISO-8859-1 as default encoding. In fact htmlspecialchars() as of PHP 5.4 uses UTF-8. You might expect, that htmlspecialchars() would just skip non-UTF-8 byte sequences or translate them to a ‘no found’ character. In fact, htmlspecialchars() returns a blank string: No error gets generated, no errorcode gets returned, no exception gets raised, just a blank string gets returned if non-valid UTF-8 sequences get passed in

Comment: This isn't an answer. `$curlData` is populated. Also an "answer" with just "use" and is pretty unhelpful. The OP knows nothing about what the code is doing or why they should be using it.

Comment: Did you run the code as is? It works. `htmlentities()` is not the issue, it will just bring the code back entitized; not empty as OP states is the issue `both header and body are empty`. Snippet of return: `&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;`

Comment: When i run his code and var_dump(htmlentities($curlData)); return string(0)"" so i assume that is the problem

Comment: I get back `string(49035) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with `htmlentities` and `string(37714) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with `html_entity_decode`. None of which are empty so a function is not the issue as I see it.

Comment: @chris85  i updated my answare, i assume you test his code with same charset as source, problem apears when using different encoding for script and source

Comment: Then write that, that would be an answer. I've used latin1 for the PHP file because OP hasn't stated anything about charsets. In my experience misencoded characters still return though, not empty.

Comment: Could be the issue I run 5.3.17 so I wouldn't experience this. Good now that you've provided context.

Comment: htmlentities($curlData, ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1' ); is working, I can now see the HTML code. Thanks a lot :)